# What timezone to use for manila, philippines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Running rake time:zones:all does not list any timezone for Manila.
What should I use in my application for manila/philippines timezone?

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question, it would be helpful if you could state the reason as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Time.zone = 'Asia/Manila'`

What you are seeing from `rake time:zones:all` are just some common aliases and it's not a complete list.

If you want the full list of supported timezones, use `TZInfo::Timezone.all`.

Comment: Great answer!  Note that this requires the [TZInfo gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/), and not just [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), which is too limiting IMHO. [See here also](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-talk/3oUESnDSR6A/AC5BlUh1JREJ).  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to just specify by utc offset, so you don't need to go hunting for a city name?

Comment: you can also use `TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Manila')` to simply get a tz object without modifying `Time.zone`